# opacity usercontrol c#.net 3.5

Tags: c#, user-controls, opacity

Why does not a user control have the 'Opacity' property? How can I use set the property on a user control?

Comment: WinForms or WPF? (EDIT: that's probably WinForms, because those who are used to WPF proudly say it, while those who don't know about it think WinForms is the only way to do GUI in C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `winforms`

To make a UserControl transparent, we have to give it a `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` style, override its `OnPaintBackground` method to draw the background with the `opacity`, and then invalidates its Parent to redraw the control whenever we need to update the graphics

Answer (score 0):

For `WinForms`

You can just set User Control Background property to `Transparent` in web colors tab

but for opacity such as 50% i am looking for a solution.